# Rich Text Editor Recommendation - Needs support for image upload and resizing

Tags: django, editor, tinymce, yui, wysiwyg

I am looking for WYSIWYG rich text editor to use with Django. I've looked at a number of different editors (CKEditor, TinyMCE, Aloha, YUI), but I can't seem to find one that has one necessary feature: dynamic image resizing.

What I mean by that is the ability to click a corner of the image in the editor and drag your mouse to resize the image. Content around the image should then adapt to the new image size. As well, the editor needs to have image upload functionality.

Any recommendations?

It's fine if its an editor+plugin combo. Ideally it would also integrate nicely with Django.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, I guess I didn't look hard enough. YUI has an optional Resize Utility that allows for dynamics resizing of images in the editor (example: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/resize/rte_resize.html). Still, I'd be interested if anyone has experience with YUI in general and would recommend it?

Comment: I don't see anything special in that sample. Both CKEditor and TinyMCE have the same features, it's the browser the one that provides the image resizing.

Comment: AlfonsoML, you are completely correct. I had both Firefox and Chrome open when testing the demos, and Firefox allows for image resizing in all of theme while Chrome does not, it appears. I've decided to go with CKEditor, as django-ckeditor (https://github.com/shaunsephton/django-ckeditor) makes it very easy to add to my Django project.

Answer (score 1):

Yup. I came to the same conclusion too. django-ckeditor is really easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

[Froala](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) and [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) are perfect for your case. They're paid though.

[QuillJS](https://quilljs.com/) is a free alternative that allows image manipulations by inserting the image directly as a base64 encoded string.